# Cannot execute alert

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a javascript code wherein a alert is to be provided when a condition gets executed

I referred some youtube videos on ajax and json and wrote a code wherein i successfully log data from a website and send an automated alert message. My issue is that whenever I add the same alert message in the if statement the alert does not get executed.

I tried using the developer tools for f12 and debugged the code it seems the data does not enter the loop.

Please help me on this

```js
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET', 'https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json');
ourRequest.onload = function() {
    var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);

    console.log(ourData);
    if (ourData = "cat") {
      alert(" take action");

    };
    ourRequest.send();
}
```

The alert should be generated as cat is found in the json file located at the link https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json

Comment: your if is not well formatted it should use the comparison operator `==`  . Correct your if with the right operator because you used `=` which is the affectation operator. By the way I checked the data and you should iterate over the object list and check the "species" attribute. Like this `if(ourData.species == "cat")`. Hope it helps.

Comment: still ourData is the response json, right? How is it equals to cat?

Comment: As well as the `=` / `==` problem, and at least one other syntax error (which should be visible in your F12 console), `ourData` is going to contain **everything** in that JSON file. So obviously it will never equal the simple word "cat". It's going to be an array of objects. "cat" occurs in two of the objects within the array, as the value of the object's "species" property. Are you looking for a specific one? Or trying to see if any of the species fields contains "cat", or what? What you're doing does not appear to make any sense.

Comment: `=` is assingment you need to compare as `==` or `===`

Comment: Typo. Missing `}`

Comment: "the data does not enter the loop" — What loop? There **should** be a loop because the JSON represents an array, but you haven't written a loop in the code you've shared to deal with it.

Comment: @ Quentin i have not included the loop in the code here as it was not required to explain my issue. I am just telling that the data does not go into the loop

Comment: @ ADyson I am looking for a specific case wherein species = cat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting my answer there instead of comment because it's too long.

Your if is not well formatted it should use the comparison operator `==` or `===` (which is "better"). Correct your if with the right operator because you used `=` which is the affectation operator.

By the way I checked the data and you should iterate over the object list and check the "species" attribute. Like this `if(ourData.species == "cat")`.

Your code should look like :

```
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET', 'https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json', true);

ourRequest.onload = function () {
  // Request finished. Do processing here.
  var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);

  console.log(ourData);
  // loop over each "animal" element
  ourData.forEach(function (element) {
    if (element.species === "cat") {
      alert(" take action");
    };
  });
};


ourRequest.send();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `element.species === "cat"`

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini oops bad copy/paste.. fixed

Comment: @huzefa.s I just edited my code to fix it! I didn't realize that `send()` was inside the `onload` while it shouldn't be (or your request will never be sent...)

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy it really served the purpose

Comment: @Flo any idea how to get data from a database saved at a private ip into the JSON  code? I will use the same code but instead of an http address I have a database at a private IP.

Comment: @huzefa.s you won't be able to query database directly from your front code. You need for example a NodeJS app with the specific database package (mysql, postgres or mongo... for example). Then build a route on your NodeJS App so your front app can call that API URL